# How to add observation on WKWebView Navigation back and forward Action?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have one requirement to add an observation on `WKWebView` backward action. `WKWebView` executes a back backward than calling my method. how can I perform this?

how can check `WKWebView` is doing back or forward action?

how many time is user doing a back action on `WKWebView`? how can I get this count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods of the WKNavigationDelegate protocol help you implement custom behaviors that are triggered during a web view's process of accepting, loading, and completing a navigation request.

You can use that delegate method :

```
webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)
```

Implementation would be like :

```
    if(navigationAction.navigationType == .backForward)
    {
        if navigationAction.request.url != nil
        {
            //do what you need with url. If Your URL is last visited then It's back.

        }
        return
    }
```

For more info please refer : [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationtype)